# WPF DataGridColumn won't let me set ".width = double.NaN" for auto-sizing columns. "Value should not be infinity" error?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, width, double, datagridcolumn

I have a WPF DataGrid and I am setting up columns manually in code behind. I am trying to set the column size to Auto with the following code:

```
customBoundColumn.Width = double.NaN;
```

But then at run-time I get the following error:

*Value should not be infinity.
Parameter name: value*

I read in many places that double.NaN is what is used to set the column size to auto. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. customBoundColumn is an instance of DataGridBoundColumn

Comment: Are you sure the error message is referring to the code you showed us?  You're setting `Width` to `NaN`, but it's complaining that you set `value` to infinity.

Comment: Yes, VS 2010 stop at this line of code, and highlights it yellow. I too am confused with the reference to 'value'

Comment: @Caustix Cheers and PF answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can simply use `DataGridLength.Auto` to set your width back to `Auto`

```
customBoundColumn.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
```

Comment: That gives "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.GridLength' to 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength'"

Comment: @Caustix Use `DataGridLength.Auto` instead. I forgot that `Grid` and `DataGrid` have different size properties

Answer (score 3):

In versions prior to .Net 4.0, the width of a datagrid column is set as

```
         customBoundColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
```

I am not sure what is it in .Net 4.0.

Comment: This works great but the answer by Rachel is the most elegant! +1

Answer (score 0):

Deafult width and height is Auto for all FrameworkElement-derived classes and so is for dataGrid columns. So, why do you need to set it explicitly in code behind?

Comment: If it has been previously set to a value then I need to be able to set it back to auto